# Erasing value in textarea if special text is typed in

Tags: javascript, html

I want to erase the value of textarea if `<br>` is typed in. Currently I only have the code below. I know the question sounds quite strange but I am trying to use the code with a type effect.

```
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Okay, that should erase the text. Now bind to `change` event and check the text for that kill sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea id="textarea"> text <br />  text </textarea> 

<script>
document.getElementById('textarea').onkeyup = function() {
   if (/<br \/>/m.test(this.value))
       this.value = '';
};
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sVbuy/)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
document.getElementById("textarea1").onkeyup = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("textarea1").indexOf("<br>") !== -1) {
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to not continually re-query the DOM for the element, but close 'nuff.

Comment: I thought about adding that but I don't think that advice is relevant in this context. If you assign a variable you should really also wrap it in an immediate function and I don't want to confuse the OP by being nit-picky.

Comment: Oh dear [omnipotent being], don't use `this` :|

Comment: Also, better to use `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` instead of `onkeyup`. Why not use `this`? Compatibility?

Comment: Yes yes, better to use a proper framework that hides the native DOM API cause it's bad.

Comment: I don't know if that was meant to refute using `this` or a joke. Also, you have a syntax error on the `.indexOf()` line.

Comment: And I don't agree with your reasoning on avoiding `this`.

Comment: If you want a proper reason to avoid `this`: `this` is confusing, it can lead to unexpected bugs, you can build any application without using `this`. The only acceptable use of `this` is when you're dealing with prototypes - which should be rare because very few situations inherently require inheritance. That is my stance on `this`. In this case, you can build it without using `this`. Feel free to post your own solution.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - I'm punting to you here; suffice it to say I think there's some bad advice being given, but I'd like to see what you think, if you have any comment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish honestly, I don't feel like getting into a debate right now. I agree that Frits is giving some subpar advice. Tear into it if you want, but I've got higher priority things to deal with for now. My will to fight JavaScript FUD is running dry.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - A version of that was my original comment, but I didn't know if I was being crotchety.

Comment: I'm not giving any advice. You attack me and cut down behind my back without giving any arguments of your own? What is this?